# ActionScript 3 Selecting a MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, textbox, movieclip

My situation is this:
I've got several (2+) MovieClips on the stage.
Each one contains an input-textbox in addition to the background.

When I click the first MovieClip, it gets selected and a light blue shadow is displayed to indicate it like so: http://puu.sh/aueAw/3575e83aca.png

If I click the second one, it looks like this: http://puu.sh/aueEj/826e1c9cb9.png

However, when the second MovieClip's textbox is clicked, the first MovieClip becomes selected! This doesn't make any sense to me.

What could be causing this? Everything works as it should as long as I don't take these nested textboxes into account.

Thanks in advance for your helpful answers!

Best regards,
Olin K.

EDIT: Here's the code that I use to add event listeners to the MovieClips.

```
public function updateVisualDocument()
{
        if (!uniDocument.isEmpty())
        {
            //Update the Visual Document if the current Document contains any pages
            visualDocument.uniPage.gotoAndStop(uniDocument.getCurrentPage().getLayout());
            visualDocument.uniPage.pageNumber.text = uniDocument.getPageIndex();

            //Update Thumbnails
            for each (var someThumb in thumbnailArray)
            {
                someThumb.deselect();
            }
            thumbnailArray[uniDocument.getPageIndex() - 1].select();

            for (var i:int = 0; i < visualDocument.uniPage.panelContainer.numChildren; i++)
            {
                var somePanelMC = visualDocument.uniPage.panelContainer.getChildAt(i);
                if (!uniDocument.getCurrentPage().hasPanels())
                {
                    uniDocument.getCurrentPage().addPanel(somePanelMC);
                }
                somePanelMC.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, panelClicked);

                uniDocument.getCurrentPage().getPanel(i).setPanelMC(somePanelMC);

                function panelClicked(e:Event)
                {
                    //Panel gets selected
                    var panelIndex:int = int(e.target.name.substring(5));
                    uniDocument.getCurrentPage().deselectAllPanels();
                    uniDocument.getCurrentPage().getPanel(panelIndex).select();
                }
            }
            uniDocument.getCurrentPage().panelsAreFull();
            uniDocument.getCurrentPage().selectFirst();
        }
    }
```

EDIT: I tried changing the textbox to the dynamic text (from the input text) type and the problem is still exactly the same. I click the textbox, it selects the first MovieClip. I think it may have to do with using the same instance name, but since it's nested, why should it matter?

Comment: For anyone to help you, you will _have_ to show the code you are using that is exhibiting this problem.

Comment: did you accidentally give them the same instance name?

Comment: @LDMS, The textboxes are all "myText.text", however the panels have instance names of "Panel1", "Panel2", "Panel3", and so on. In the screenshots I provided in the original post, there are only two panels, but there can be more panels than just two (depending on the layout), and every layout exhibits this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I figured it out on my own. Partially. I worked off what LDMS said in his comment "did you accidentally give them the same instance name?"

Well, no, I didn't. BUT- the textboxes all had the same instance name. This is irrelevant, but it got me focused on the textboxes names, and I realized that since I had `mouseChildren` set to `false`, the textboxes were the ones firing off the event listener.

So I changed up a bit of my code to look like this:

```
function panelClicked(e:Event)
{
    //Panel gets selected
    if (!e.target.name == "myText")
    {
        var panelIndex:int = int(e.target.name.substring(5));
        uniDocument.getCurrentPage().deselectAllPanels();
        uniDocument.getCurrentPage().getPanel(panelIndex).select();
    }
}
```

And now it works! It's a simple workaround, since doing `myText.mouseEnabled = false;` was not an option because it needed to be clicked.

Hope this helps someone in the future! Cheers!